# Javascript onkeyup user defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did well so far, but i am not able to implement this into an html object.
http://jsfiddle.net/fkyk2b8y/48/
Let's assume i have an html element like `<input type='text' id="textareaID" onkeyup="myFunction(this.id)" />` and  i'd like to implement like this :

```
function myFunction(elementID){
   $('#'+elementID).keypress(function (e){
      ...
      ...
      ...
   });
}
```

It doesn't work properly after implementation as you can try from the fiddle demo.

Thanks in advance.

---UPDATE---

I have many html outputs and they all have different ID values. I want to use same function for all of these html inputs. I don't know how to implement, otherwise JS side is working quite well.

Comment: Why you need `onclick` on element and in `javascript` also?

Comment: @Tushar yes i realized that it is wrong, so how can i get the function(e)'s value without using .keypress ?

Comment: Use `keypress` in javascript, remove inline handler

Comment: What is exactly not working? it seems your function is been called by keypress, but then what is the desired output that you want?

Comment: @Newinjava i have many html outputs and they all have different ID values. I want to use same function for all of these html inputs. I don't know how to implement, otherwise JS side is working quite well.

Comment: Ok, you want reusabilty, that's easy to do. Beyond that, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish and why it's not working (if it isn't)

Comment: @JSelser yes i want reusability. I just cannot implement the reusable kind version.

Comment: you can use something like this. $('input[type=text]').keypress

Comment: @blankBird_ I have added an answer, check if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for your patience and sharing information. This was what i really meant to do :

Html part :

```
<input type='text' id="textareaID" onkeypress="currencyChecker(event, this.id)" />
<span></span>
```

JS part:
https://jsfiddle.net/fkyk2b8y/54/

Answer (score 1):

you'r trying to put jQuery keypress event inside onkeyup function event...

just do that this way:

```
<input type='text' id="textareaID" />
```

and inside the :

```
 $("textareaID").keypress(function (e){
    if ( e.keyCode == (whatever you want) ) ...
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to apply a function to all desired inputs, in order to achieve reusability, you can use a `class` instead of an `id`. So change `<input id="textareaID" ... />` to `<input class="textarea" ... />`

Now define make your anonymous function a named one outside the event handler binding. So instead of:

```
$('#textareaID').keypress(function(e){ ... });
```

You'd have:

```
function reusableFunction(e){ ... }

$('.textarea').keypress(reusableFunction);
```

Also in your jsFiddle you need to replace a few `document.getElementById`'s for `this`. Here's your [jsFiddle with said modifications](https://jsfiddle.net/fkyk2b8y/48/). Notice I have 3 inputs like the original and if I want more I can just add the `class`.

I'd love to update my answer if I missed something, you don't mention why your function is broken and is not immediately obvious.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have already thought of using class values. But i am using twitter bootstrap. So my inputs are like these <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text text-right"> kind. So what do you offer ?

Comment: No problem. If you have `class="form-control input-sm text text-right"` you can always add another class at the end, like:  `class="form-control input-sm text text-right textarea"`

Comment: As soon as i am able to try, i will give you the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me understand this, do you want to call a jQuery function from a javascript function while passing the element's id? And then use both the element's id and the keypress event??
 If so, it could be done like this,

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="callKeyPress(this.id);" id="textId" />

    <span id="keypressCode">0</span>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("function is ready to use now");
});



$.fn.keyPressFunction = function(id){
    alert("id is ---> "+id);

var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        $('#keypressCode').html(keycode);

    //do something with key code

}

function callKeyPress(id){
    alert(id);
    $.fn.keyPressFunction(id);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to do. I will try this one too and feedback. Thank you so much.

Comment: sure.. do let me know if it helps and if you get stuck again anywhere

Comment: also note, you need not pass event exclusively to the function you are calling on keypress to get the key code..

Comment: Okay but how will the browser will bind them both ? Yes i am a little bit confused, sorry

Comment: when you say,
`onkeypress="callKeyPress(this.id);"` . 
First, the keypress event is bound using onkeypress() function call, second, we pass the element's id exclusively using `this.id`. This bit is simple. Next when you call a jQuery function, i.e., `$.fn.keyPressFunction(id)` from within the `onkeypress()` function, the event is auto bound, i.e., the event object exists within the scope of the execution of preceding `callKeyPress()` function unless you say `event.stopPropagation()` and yeah, you pass the id of the element as well.  I admit, it would sound a bit confusing, tried explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

Html

```
<input type='text' id="textareaID1" />
<input type='text' id="textareaID2" />
<span></span>
```

Js

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup',function(e){
    $('span').html(this.id);
});
```

you stated in your comment that there can be many inputfields with different ids, so you can do this

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/fkyk2b8y/50/